# php как вложить в письмо $_POST полностью

Tags: php, post, email

Есть форма с неизвестным количеством инпутов вида

```
input type="text" name="order[inputname]"
```

Что мне написать в php файле обработчике формы, чтобы содержимое всех инпутов вложилось в тело письма и отправилось по указанному адресу.

Comment: Может цикл foreach? `foreach($_POST as $key => $value) { ... }`

Comment: Почему то не работает. Где ошибка?

     $text="";
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$val) {
    $text=$text.$key.$val."<br>";
    }'

Comment: А что приходит если в цикле писать? Вместо `<br/>` наверное надо `\r\n`  и цикл какой-то непрвильный.. когда имя `order[inputname]` то каждое значение перетирает предыдущее...если инпутов с таким именем много.....лучше покажите весь `html` и как и что в `php` вы делаете......... скорее всего вам нужен цикл по `$_POST['order']`

Comment: В письме приходит

    formArray<br>

Comment: Вот html код формы. http://codepen.io/mxd/pen/MyzyXX?editors=1010
вот send.php http://codepen.io/mxd/pen/WwYwKX?editors=1000
 Я не очень понимаю как он работает, поэтому выкладываю его целиком.

Comment: ну ок. А консолью и Network'ом вы пользоваться тоже не умеете? ... вам же там черным по белому пишут что отправляется `form[Name]:asd
form[Subject]:123
form[Send]:Отправить
form[formId]:4` ..... соответственно и цикл будет `foreach($_POST['form'] as $key=>$val) { .....` ... а лучше из пост запроса убрать поле `Subject` ..... умейте пользоваться инструментами разработчика

Comment: Разобрался! Спасибо большое за детальное пояснение на что следует смотреть

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Comment: не делай так это боль

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="text"  name="order[]" >

$text = '';

foreach ($_POST['order'] as $key => $value) {
    if ($value != null)
           $text.= $value;
}

echo $text;
```

Comment: В ответах принято давать пояснение, а не только код.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?